# Xcode 6.1: UITableViewcontroller template empty

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

When I try to generate a new `UITableViewController` in **Xcode 6.1** for an **IOS 8.1** iPhone project with

`File->New->File->Cocoa Class` and then select "Subclass of `UITableViewController`", Language `Swift`, I get a source file like this:

```
//
//  xxx.swift
//  project
//
//  Created by Olaf Klein on 29/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Olaf Klein. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa

class xxx: UITableViewController {

}
```

Of course I expected a much bigger class with some methods - reinstalling Xcode doesn't change anything - any hints?

Comment: Are you asking about iOS or OS X? You've tagged your question OS X, and you say you're going to Cocoa Class, but Cocoa doesn't have a UITableViewController.

Comment: as i wrote above, its a IOS project. The second cool thing is, the import is marked as an error (the small red circle with exclamation mark and the error message: "no such module 'cocoa'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're choosing the wrong file type to add. Cocoa is the framework for OS X development, and it has no UITableViewController class, so there is no template, and the Cocoa module will not be included in your project.

From the new file dialogue you have to choose from the iOS section, a new Cocoa *Touch* file, I think (away from my Mac at the moment, and they keep changing the arrangement of that section).

This will give you the proper template.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.

Comment: how i can change default template ?